# Change color of hovered section's label in React-chartjs2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I have a line chart, and on hover section i need to change color of corresponding label on x-axis.

[This is my line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBfZW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.